# Sum strings that have an optional slash in them

Tags: javascript, reduce

I need to sum all of the values in an array of strings, some of which are empty, some are normal integers, some are separated by slashes. I have it working when the values are just integers or empty, but not when they are separated by slashes.

```
//this works and should total 30
//var data = ["","1","","2","3","10","14"];

//this doesn't work and should total 166, not 128
var data = ["","1","2","5 / 35","","100 / 3", "20"];

var sum = data.reduce(function (a, b) {
    a = parseInt(a, 10);
    if(isNaN(a)){ a = 0; }

    b = parseInt(b, 10);
    if(isNaN(b)){ b = 0; }

    return a + b;
});

console.log(sum);
```

Here is a codepen with the example...

https://codepen.io/murphydan/pen/GGWwgE?editors=0011

Comment: How are the ones with slashes supposed to be interpreted? Division?

Comment: "5 / 35" is two different numbers. This is a dumbed down version of the real problem. It is data coming from a DataTable, so we know some of the rows have values like "5 / 35" to show two different data sets happening on the same day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you simply want to sum all numbers in the array, no matter what's the elements content (as your desired result is 166). You can simply split and use another reduce

```js
const data = ["", "1", "2", "5 / 35", "", "100 / 3", "20"];
const res = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  const t = b.split('/');
  return a + t.reduce((x, y) => x + Number(y), 0);
}, 0);


console.log(res);
```

---

If you need it even more flexible, for example if the slash could also be something else, like a comma, dash or whatever, you could split by non digits too. `split(/\D/)`. This will create some more array entries as every whitespace gets another entry, but that doesn't change the result.

Answer (score -1):

I like to avoid nesting functions like `.reduce()`.

Like:

```js
const data = ["", "1", "2", "5 / 35", "", "100 / 3", "20"];

const res = data.join(' ')// to a single string
    .replace(/\//g, '')// replace all slashes
    .split(/\s/)// split on whitespace to array
    .reduce((acc, n) => (acc + (parseInt(n) || 0)) ,0);// sum all numbers
 


console.log(res);
```